# How do I get the size of a mesh which was scaled by a bone in three.js?

Tags: three.js, gltf

My project is a little javascript webgame with three.js.

I use the GLTFLoader to import a GLTF file with animations into my project. The model is loaded and i can play all the animations.
My goal is make the network traffic as small as possible. That's why I want to import only a few GLTF models as base models and change their appearance on the client side with three.js.
By scaling specific bones of a model, I can make the model look tall without interfere with the animations of the skeleton.

The only Problem is:

If I change the size of a model, by scaling some bones, the model size is changed on the whole Y-axis. Positive and negative.

For Example:

If I place a 'human' model on a plane and than scale the model by scaling a bone, the feet of the model are moved below the plane because of the scaling.
That is why I need to know the exact height or size of my model before and after I changed the size by scaling a bone. This way I could calculate how far I need to push the model above the plane.

I tried

```
mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()
```

and than get the size of the boundingBox, but that just give me the size of the unchanged geometry of my model.

I also tried to create a new Box3 object and make it the same size as my changed model by using:

```
new Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
```

But that also just gives me the unchanged size of the geometry.

So, how do I get the size of a mesh which was scaled by a bone in three.js?
Or is there a different way to solve my problem?

Looking forward to reading your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Skinning (vertex transformation caused by bones) is applied on the GPU for performance reasons, and vertex positions are never read back into application memory. As a result, methods like `geometry.computeBoundingBox()`, `mesh.scale`, and raycasting will not take skinning into account.

If your use case is simple (e.g. only one bone affects skinning) you can always get the scale of that particular bone and multiply it against the original bounding box:

```
var bone = model.getObjectByName('MyScalingBone');
console.log(bone.scale);
```